# Android Logo in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the android logo using only HTML and CSS (inspiration linked here: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-android-logo).

I compared my css code to the ones on the linked site multiple times and I don't know what is wrong. Can someone offer fresh eyes and help?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Android Logo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="android">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="l_ant"></div>
                <div class="r_ant"></div>
                <div class="l_eye"></div>
                <div class="r_eye"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="l_arm"></div>
                <div class="r_arm"></div>
                <div class="l_leg"></div>
                <div class="r_leg"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</hmtl>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
div{
    margin:o;
    padding:0;
}

div div{
    background:#A4CA39;
    position:relative;
}


.android{
    height:404px;
    width:334px;
    margin:100px auto;
}

.head{
    width:220px;
    height:100px;
    top:32px;

    border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:110px 110px 0 0;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}

.l_eye, .r_eye{
    background:#fff;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:42px;

    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}

.l_eye{
    left:50px;
}

.r_eye{
    right:50px;
}

.l_ant, .r_ant{
    width:6px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-34px;

    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
}

.l_ant{
    left:50px;
    transform:rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-30deg);
}


.r_ant{
    right:50px;
    transform:rotate(30deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(30deg);

}

.body{
    width:220px;
    height:184px;
    top:40px;

    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}

.l_arm, .r_arm, .l_leg, .r_leg{
    width:50px;
    postion:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}

.l_arm, .r_arm,{
    height:150px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
}

.l_leg, .r_leg{
    height:80px;
    top:182px;
    border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}


.l_arm{
    left: -58px;
}

.r_arm{
    right: -58px;
}

.l_leg{
    left: 45px;
}

.r_leg{
    right: -135px;
}

.head:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) translate(-4px, -8px);
    -transform:rotate(-5deg)translate(-4px, -8px);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-5deg)translate(-4px, -8px);
}

.l_arm:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-14px, 0);
    -transform:rotate(15deg)translate(-14px, 0);
    -moz-transform:rotate(15deg)translate(-14px, 0);
}

.r_arm:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(30px, 0);
    -transform:rotate(-30deg)translate(30px, 0);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-30deg)translate(30px, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following. You have some mistakes in css like `.r_leg{ right: -135px; }` Should be `.r_leg {right: 45px;}`

```
.l_arm, .r_arm, .l_leg, .r_leg{
    width:50px;
    postion:absolute; // Here spelling mistake postion should be position
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

Above css have spelling mistake.

remove last `,` from `.l_arm, .r_arm,{`

```css
div {margin: o; padding: 0;}
div div {background: #A4CA39; position: relative;}

.android{
 height: 404px; width: 334px;
 margin: 100px auto;
 
}
.head{
 width: 220px; height: 100px;
 top: 32px;
 
 border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 110px 110px 0 0;
 
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
.l_eye, .r_eye {
 background: #fff;
 width: 20px; height: 20px;
 position: absolute; top: 42px;
 
 border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
.l_eye {left: 50px;}
.r_eye {right: 50px;}

.l_ant, .r_ant{
 width: 6px; height: 50px;
 position: absolute; top: -34px;
 
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
 -moz-border-radius: 3px;
}
.l_ant {
 left: 50px;
 transform: rotate(-30deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.r_ant {
 right: 50px;
 transform: rotate(30deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.body{
 width: 220px; height: 184px;
 top: 40px;
 
 border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}

.l_arm, .r_arm, .l_leg, .r_leg {
 width: 50px; position: absolute;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}
.l_arm, .r_arm {
 height: 150px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
}
.l_leg, .r_leg {
 height: 80px; top: 182px;
 border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;
}
.l_arm {left: -58px;}
.r_arm {right: -58px;}
.l_leg {left: 45px;}
.r_leg {right: 45px;}

.head:hover {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg) translate(-4px, -8px);
 -transform: rotate(-5deg) translate(-4px, -8px);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg) translate(-4px, -8px);
}
.l_arm:hover{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-14px, 0);
 -transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-14px, 0);
 -moz-transform: rotate(15deg) translate(-14px, 0);
}
.r_arm:hover{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(30px, 0);
 -transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(30px, 0);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg) translate(30px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="android">
            <div class="head">
                <div class="l_ant"></div>
                <div class="r_ant"></div>
                <div class="l_eye"></div>
                <div class="r_eye"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="body">
                <div class="l_arm"></div>
                <div class="r_arm"></div>
                <div class="l_leg"></div>
                <div class="r_leg"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```